# How did websites like Upwork hide pages they don't want users based on roles?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using reactjs, nodejs, Mongo, jwt, expressjs and axios to build blog application. I always stored user roles in local storage to enable me use it persistently across the app components in react to hide and show some pages based on user role.
If a user edits their role in local storage, they would see the pages that were hidden from them. Let say a user edits their role from user to admin, they would see some texts written in reactjs meant for only admin. I'm not talking about the server side verification now. I know the user may not be able to perform admin actions since that has been checked from the backend. But how about pages rendered in reactjs. How best to store data such as user role for frontend to use persistently since localstorage is not good enough?

My Upwork account doesn't have such information in my localstorage, that made me to wonder where such website stores theirs.
I came across in-memory storage of such data. Is this cool? Or what is best?

Comment: Authorization should be managed on the back-end. If you request a resource and don't have the required permissions, the back-end should not serve that resource, simple as that. Managing anything security-related on the front-end is pointless.

Comment: what Robby said.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm still new in the field though. I wanted to know, does backend have access to react pages? I have designed a login page in react. If i wanted to hide that page, not the ability to login, but the login page I designed in react to be displayed only to users who are not admin, can that be done in backend too? So far, I know I can do that for api call in backend, I really don't know how that can be done for pages designed in react via html and css.

Comment: when a user log in you get a data back from server telling you the user role .so simply you need to store that `role` value in a global state (e.g. redux or context ) like `role:admin` then you can get that value on any component

Answer (score 0):

You can define a property called `role` in your `database` and it could have multiple values such as `admin`, `teacher`, `student`, etc.

Now when a `user` logs in to the website, you can store the `role` of the `user` in the `localStorage` or get it every time a `user` makes a `request` to the `backend`.

And then you can get the `role` property in the `frontend` and check the `authorization` level of the `user`.

If you are using `react`, you can do it in the `app.js` file like below:

```
const App = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
      // Making the request to get the user from backend and storing it in the user state
    })
    return (
      <Router>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/action" element={< Action />} />
            <Route path="/edit-action" element={< EditActions />} />
            <Route path="/add-actions" element={< AddActions />} />
            
            <Route path="/products" element={< Products />} />
            <Route path="/edit-product" element={< AddProducts />} />
            <Route path="/add-products" element={< AddProducts />} />

            {/* Only allowed to the admin */}
            if(user.role === 'admin') {
              <Route path="/broker-firm" element={< BrokerFirm />} />
              <Route path="/add-broker-firm" element={< AddBrokerFirm />} />
              <Route path="/edit-broker-firm" element={< EditBrokerFirm />} />
            }

        </Routes>
      </Router>
    )
}
```

Now as defined in the above code `BrokeFirm`, `AddBrokerFirm`, `EditBrokerFirm` will only be allowed to `admin`.

But still, I would recommend checking in every `component` the `role` of the `user` because that way your website will be more secure.

Comment: This looks interesting. With this, I may not need to store such information in localstorage at all. Because that is what I want to avoid. It is more like an in-memory storage using useEffects to fetch the user from backend and check their roles directly.

Comment: Well, As I said getting the `user role` in every `component` will be more secure.